# Grape 'text' type parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-grape, grape-api, grape-entity

I have a column type `TEXT` in my database. What type of parameter should I declare in my API?

```
params do
  requires :body, type: Text
end
```

The code above produces this `error: uninitialized constant API::Articles::Text (NameError)`

I tried setting the parameter as a `type: String`, but my test responded with an `ArgumentError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow API params doesn't accept column name `body`. This was the reason for the error. I managed to solve it by changing the attribute name.